# How to import custom file extension to an iOS project on XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, plist

I have tried to add the new customized file extension ".uuu" into my iOS application, the .PDF and .ZIP formats I added are working, but .uuu format doesn't work. I don't know where I did wrong, I checked the plist for several times but no luck.

Here the info.plist content of the file extension below:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
                <array>
                    <string>pdf</string>
                </array>
                <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                <string>pdf</string>
                <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                <string>None</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDFReader</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>

    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
                <array>
                    <string>zip</string>
                </array>
                <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                <string>zip</string>
                <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                <string>None</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Zip</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.zip-archive</string>
        </array>
    </dict>

    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
                <array>
                    <string>uuu</string>
                </array>
                <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
                <string>uuu</string>
                <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
                <string>None</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>UUU</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.uuuFiles</string>
        </array>
    </dict>

</array>
```

The uuu file is gray in the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Info.plist content is very strange. Look you have a key of `CFBundleDocumentTypes` which has as value an array. In this array *again* you have key `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and its content is not correct. Some elements are inside and some outside.

You should do it a bit differently. I will fix up the first one and then you do the others the same and see how it goes.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
      <array>
        <string>pdf</string>
      </array>
      <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
      <string>pdf</string>
      <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
      <string>None</string>
      <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
      <array/>
      <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
      <string>PDFReader</string>
      <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

For a good reference create a new document based app and look at its Info.plist. You probably also need an entry in the `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` section for your specific type.

Comment: still no luck. I have use "public.data" instead. It allows to open any file types. But I still don't know how to open the specific .uuu file.

Comment: Did you add the ```UTExportedTypeDeclarations``` key to Info.plist?

Comment: Yes, I added UTExportedTypeDeclarations

Comment: Ok - should work, update your dump to show the latest Info.plist's CFBundleDocumentTypes and UTExportedTypeDeclarations.